# filter view by parent of a taxonomy term

Tags: 7, views

In drupal 7, how can I filter content of node type by the parent of a taxonomy term, such that if the content has a child of this taxonomy term it will come out if the parent is chosen as the filter ?

I want to be able to add children without having to modify the view each time as to which terms are in the filter, having it rely only on the parent as the filter by term.(can be done using depth level from the parent term)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a view filter as **Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth)** which describes as -

Display content if it has the selected taxonomy terms, or children of the selected terms. Due to additional complexity, this has fewer options than the versions without depth.

You can select one of the parent term and set the depth of its child terms too.